# A QSplitter and finding the current widget

Tags: qt

I have a QSplitter with four QTextEdit widgets inside. I know that I can use QObject::findChildren to receive a list with all the widgets inside a widget (in my case in the QSplitter) but I can't figure it out how to determine which is the current one?

Comment: What does it mean to be the current one? The QTextEdit which has the focus?

Comment: yes, the one that has the focus.

Comment: Don't think there is a method in QSplitter to do that, but maybe QApplication::focusWidget() help : http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qapplication.html#focusWidget

Comment: Actually, Daniel Castro's question helped me and I tried with hasFocus() method and it works. Thank you! [Solved]

Comment: Consider writing the solution as an answer so it is easily visible for other people with the same issue :)

Comment: I don't have enough points to answer my questions

Comment: Then, if you want, I can post the answer

Comment: Of course, go ahead :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, you were looking for the QTextEdit with the focus, so there are two options, basically:

1. Use QApplication::focusWidget() (http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qapplication.html#focusWidget)
2. Loop through every child of your QSplitter and call hasFocus() for each one so you can know which of them has the focus (keyboard focus)

The main disadvantage of the first approach is that you can't be sure (using it directly) whether that widget belongs to the QSplitter or not. The second approach may sound a bit inefficent, but if your QSplitter does not have many widgets, then it will be perfectly fine.

As pointed in the comments (of the OP), you have chosen the second approach, and I'm the one posting the answer here because the OP didn't have enough reputation to answer his question.